# Filtering Objects in Arrays (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Could someone help me understand why:

```js
const people = [{
    name: "Carly",
    yearOfBirth: 1942,
    yearOfDeath: 1970,
  },
  {
    name: "Ray",
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011,
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941,
  },
];



const findTheOldest = function(array) {
  let alivePeople = array.filter(function(person) {
    console.log(person.yearOfDeath);
    if (person.yearOfDeath === true) {
      console.log(person);
      return true;
    }
  });
  return alivePeople;
};

console.log(findTheOldest(people))
```

Is showing https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3p5Q.png?

I was expecting it to return all the objects in the people array. I was trying to write code that would filter out people without a year of death.

Answer (score 5):

Your code doesn't work because `person.yearOfDeath` does not equal `true` for any of the objects in the array.

You should check whether each object has the `yearOfDeath` property, which can be done with [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn), [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), or the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). `Object.hasOwn` is recommended for modern code if there is no need to check the prototype chain.

```js
const people = [{
    name: "Carly",
    yearOfBirth: 1942,
    yearOfDeath: 1970,
  },
  {
    name: "Ray",
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011,
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941,
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    yearOfBirth: 2000
  }
];
let res = people.filter(o => Object.hasOwn(o, 'yearOfDeath'));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the job

```
const people = [
  {
    name: "Carly",
    yearOfBirth: 1942,
    yearOfDeath: 1970,
  },
  {
    name: "Ray",
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011,
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941,
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    yearOfBirth: 1920,
  }
];



const findTheOldest = function(array) {
let alivePeople = array.filter(function (person) {
  if (person.yearOfDeath != undefined) {
    return true;
  }
});
return alivePeople; 
};

console.log(findTheOldest(people))
```

Output

```
[
  { name: 'Carly', yearOfBirth: 1942, yearOfDeath: 1970 },
  { name: 'Ray', yearOfBirth: 1962, yearOfDeath: 2011 },
  { name: 'Jane', yearOfBirth: 1912, yearOfDeath: 1941 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Its doing exactly as you asked it

```
function filterOutDeadPeople(array) {
    let alivePeople = array.filter(function (person) {
      if (person.yearOfDeath === true) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return alivePeople;
  }

console.log(filterOutDeadPeople(people));
```

Will filter out dead people this is not the what you want as its to filter out alive people

```
function filterOutAlivePeople(array) {
    let deadPeople = array.filter(function (person) {
      if (person.yearOfDeath === false) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return deadPeople;
  }
```